# How to integrate ORMLite with android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am not creating any database in android.  We just copy and paste the database from assets:

```
getmyapplicationContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

How we can integrate ORMLite with our App?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.  Can you please provide more information?  I don't think you mean "copy and paste" for example.  Do you mean copy one database to another or maybe load in a bulk amount of information?

Answer (score 1):

It's no difference if you're creating database with ORMLite or use existing one. Moreover usually you create it only once, and then work on existing one.

So you should probably use:

- [How to use ORMLite with Android](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#SEC39)
- [HelloAndroid example presents how your Activity should looks like](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/)

and create ORM schema classes that correspond to all your database tables.
There you can also configure correct path to your existing database file.

Good luck ;)